# IndexedDb unit test using jest in javascript

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, indexeddb

`how to mock indexedDb in jest unit test ?I m new to jest testing and trying to to mock it. Here is my indexedDb code. its getting data from db and have functionality to create data and deletes data based on id from db.  I have dom elements also in  index db which i asseume can be mocked with jsdom.

```
let db = null;
let objectStore = null;
const DB_PERSONAL_DETAILS = "PersonalDetails";
const PERSONAL_DETAILS_STORE = "PersonalDetailsStore";
const MODE = {readWrite : "readwrite", readOnly : "readonly"};
const name = document.getElementById("name");
const email = document.getElementById("email");
const dob = document.getElementById("dob");
const phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phone");
const formMessageHolder = document.getElementById("form-message");



export function intialiseDb(){
    
    let DBOpenReq = indexedDB.open(DB_PERSONAL_DETAILS, 2);
    
    DBOpenReq.addEventListener('error', (err) => {
      //Error occurred while trying to open DB
      console.warn(err);
    });
    DBOpenReq.addEventListener('success', (ev) => {
      //DB has been opened... after upgradeneeded
      db = ev.target.result;
      getPersonaldetails();
      console.log('success', db);
    });
    DBOpenReq.addEventListener('upgradeneeded', (ev) => {
      //first time opening this DB
      //OR a new version was passed into open()
      db = ev.target.result;
      let oldVersion = ev.oldVersion;
      let newVersion = ev.newVersion || db.version;
      console.log('DB updated from version', oldVersion, 'to', newVersion);
  
      console.log('upgrade', db);
      if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(PERSONAL_DETAILS_STORE)) {
        objectStore = db.createObjectStore(PERSONAL_DETAILS_STORE, {
          keyPath: 'id',
        });
      }
    });
}

export function getPersonaldetails(){
    const tx = makeTransaction(PERSONAL_DETAILS_STORE, MODE.readOnly);

    tx.oncomplete = () => {

    }

    // this will return an Array on result onsuccess
    const getReq =  tx.objectStore(PERSONAL_DETAILS_STORE).getAll();

    getReq.onsuccess = (ev) => {
        const results = ev.target.result;
        showPersonalDetails(results);
    }

    getReq.onerror = (err) => { console.warn(err)}

}

export function showPersonalDetails(results){
    const listContainerDiv = document.getElementById("listConatinerDiv");
    const listHeader = document.getElementById("listHeader");

    results?.length ?  listHeader.innerHTML = `<h2>Personal details list</h2>` : ""


    listContainerDiv.addEventListener('click', deletePersonalDetail);

    let listItems = results?.length > 0 ? results.map((item) => {

        return `<ul>
        <li data-label='Full name'>${item.name}</li>
        <li data-label='Email'>${item.email}</li> 
        <li data-label='date of birth'>${item.dob}</li>
        <li data-label='Phone number'>${item.phoneNumber}</li>
        <li data-label='Action'><a data-key=${item.id} href = '#'> Delete <span class='visually-hidden'>${item.name}<span></a></li></ul>`
    }) : `<ul><li>No results found. </li></ul>`;

     listItems = results?.length > 0 ? listItems.join(" ") : listItems

    listContainerDiv.innerHTML = `<ul>
    <li>First Name</li>
    <li>Email</li>
    <li>Date of birth</li>
    <li>Phone Number</li>
    <li>Action</li>
  </ul>` + listItems;

}

export function makeTransaction(storeName, mode){
    const tx =  db.transaction(storeName, mode);

    tx.onerror = (err) => {
        console.warn(err)
    };

    return tx

}

export function deletePersonalDetail(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    if(ev.target.attributes['data-key']){

    const tx = makeTransaction(PERSONAL_DETAILS_STORE, MODE.readWrite);
    const id = ev.target.attributes['data-key'].value;
    tx.oncomplete = () => {

        formMessageHolder.innerHTML = "Data has been deleted successfully";
        getPersonaldetails();

    };

    const deleteReq = tx.objectStore(PERSONAL_DETAILS_STORE).delete(id);
    deleteReq.onsuccess = (ev) => {console.log("deleted")};
    deleteReq.onerror = (err) => {console.log(err)};
}

}

export function createDetailsinDB(formData){
    let PersonalDetailsData = {     
                                    id : crypto.randomUUID(),
                                    name : formData.nameValue,
                                    email : formData.emailValue,
                                    dob : formData.dobValue,
                                    phoneNumber : formData.phoneNumberValue
                                }

    let tx = makeTransaction(PERSONAL_DETAILS_STORE , MODE.readWrite)

    tx.oncomplete = (ev) => {
        console.log(ev);
        getPersonaldetails()
    }
//make constant for store name and db name 
    let req  = tx.objectStore(PERSONAL_DETAILS_STORE).add(PersonalDetailsData)

    req.onsuccess = (ev) => {
        console.log("successfully added")   ;
    }

    req.onerror = (err) => {
        console.log("error : " + err);
    }

}
```